Selectively clear cache during Office Addin dev/test
During development and testing of a Word AddIn, I routinely make changes to the manifest and then have to:

Clear my browser cache
Sideload my addin


Otherwise, to remove an add-in sideloaded to Office on the web, simply
clear your browser's cache.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing
I find this incredibly annoying as I have to login again to websites like stackoverflow.
Is there a way of selectively clearing the cache? ie. just clear the Microsoft Office stuff?

Which office application has the add-in been developed for?

Word. I've updated the post.

I know in dev tools in Edge there is a "do not cache" setting I used. I also setup my backend NGINX server to tell the browser not to cache. I also had a scrip that cleared the cache locally upon each startup. It is a pain!

You're testing in VSCode on Windows against the Desktop version of Word?

Yes in VSCode on Windows. No, I'm testing against the Web browser version of Word.
